# Компьютер не видно в сети

Tags: ping, сеть

Нахожусь внутри одной сети.

 Мой десктоп(OS Windows 10) подключён к роутеру через `Ethernet` и имеет ip адрес: `192.168.0.104` 
Пытаюсь пингануть ноутбук внутри сети с адресом `192.168.0.101`, успешно!
Но когда пытаюсь проделать всё наоборот `(c адреса 192.168.0.101 ping -> 192.168.0.104)` 

 
То результатом является

> "Нет ответа connection timeout"

P.S. Роутеру видно оба адреса.

Comment: Как дела обстоят с файерволом?

Comment: @RomanDanilov Никогда его не трогал. Если честно, понятие не имею о нём.

Comment: @RomanDanilov Спасибо за подсказку! Зашёл в настройки, а там стоит блокировка входящих подключений, странно,  пару месяцев назад, спокойно мог пинговать эти компьютеры